# Blender Not Rendering Properly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Only the sky is rendered, some parts of the rig, and the sword. I'm not certain as to what caused it. The blend download file is below. I could not use blendswap because it is larger than 30MB.

https://www.mediafire.com/file/drrmg4p5fhs53x9/Scene_1_Backup.blend/file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the little filter icon (See screenshot) you will see that a lot of things are turned of in your render. Simply enable the things you want to be seen, and you should be good to go.

PS: dont mind the purple, you didnt upload the textures ;P

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah thanks! The textures are from MCPrep. I've watched a tutorial on this. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, this has happened before. I'm not sure why! Is there a shortcut to turn off all render things? If so, please tell!